# Data reshaping with conditions in R

Tags: r, reshape

I am trying to reshape the data but with some conditions. The data will be like below. like this there will be more ID which are repeating

```
  S.No     Count  ID      Type  
    1         135   350      A   
    2         114   350      A  
    3         84    350      A  
    4         80    350      A  
    5         19    350      A  
    6          8    350      A  
    7         21    350      A  
    8         88    350      B  
    9        111    350      B  
    10        46    350      B  
    11       108    350      B 
    12       19     352      A
    13       117    352      A
    14       167    352      B
```

And I need to convert it like below.

```
S.No    ID  Type    Count_type B    Count_typeA_less than     Count_typeA 
                                       max(count_type B)      high than  
                                                          max(count_type B)  
1       350  B      88,111,46,108       84,80,19,8,21             135,114  
2       352  B      167                 19,117                        NA
```

**Count_typeA_Less than max(count_type B)** = count of type A which are less than maximum number of count_type B
**Count_typeA_high than max(count_type B)** = count of type A which are higher than the maximum number of count_type B

I tried with the dplyr and reshape. I could not achieve this. Please guide me for the above situation in R.

Comment: It's not clear what kind of structure your output should be? Is it a data frame? And if yes, is there a single value `88, 111, 46, 108` combined or should these be four cases (four separate values)? Or is it sufficient to just have an additional variable which indicates, for each row, whether `count type A` is less or greater than `max(count type B)`? (and what if count type A equals count type B)?

Comment: Thanks Daniel, for your response. Yes, I need it to be a data frame. The data I have has 1000 observation with different ID like this. Secondly, ya I need it as a single value where the  count are to be separated by comma. Finally, if count type A equals count type B, then a separate column showing the count that are equal (again this should be single value)

Comment: ok, so these columns need to be character vectors? E.g., first value in column ** Count_typeA_less than max(count B)** is `"88, 111, 46, 108"`?

Comment: Yes Daniel, you are right!

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to do essentially what you're asking for:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydf)

mydf[, list(type_B = toString(Count[Type == "B"]),
            type_A_lt_mB = toString(Count[Type == "A" & Count < max(Count[Type == "B"])]),
            type_A_gt_mB = toString(Count[Type == "A" & Count > max(Count[Type == "B"])])), ID]
##     ID           type_B      type_A_lt_mB type_A_gt_mB
## 1: 350 88, 111, 46, 108 84, 80, 19, 8, 21     135, 114
## 2: 352              167           19, 117
```

Here's the starting `data.frame` I used:

```
mydf <- structure(list(Count = c(135L, 114L, 84L, 80L, 19L, 8L, 21L, 
    88L, 111L, 46L, 108L, 19L, 117L, 167L), ID = c(350L, 350L, 350L, 
    350L, 350L, 350L, 350L, 350L, 350L, 350L, 350L, 352L, 352L, 352L
    ), Type = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
    "B", "A", "A", "B")), .Names = c("Count", "ID", "Type"), row.names = c(NA, 
    14L), class = "data.frame")
```

I removed the "S.no" column because it appears to be totally irrelevant to the question.